# Set width for `PivotItem` in Office UI Fabric

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I am using `Pivot` and `PivotItem` from Office UI Fabric to display my content in tabs. Currently when the tab renders, all the tabs are left aligned.

[image]

I need to display the tabs with equal width so that they occupy the 100% width of the page.

Below is the code for `Pivot`.

```
   <Pivot linkFormat={PivotLinkFormat.tabs} linkSize={PivotLinkSize.large} styles={pivotStyles}>
      <PivotItem headerText="Foo">
        <Label>Pivot #1</Label>
      </PivotItem>
      <PivotItem headerText="Bar">
        <Label>Pivot #2</Label>
      </PivotItem>
      <PivotItem headerText="Bas">
        <Label>Pivot #3</Label>
      </PivotItem>
      <PivotItem headerText="Biz">
        <Label>Pivot #4</Label>
      </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

Below is the code that I could figure out to add `styles` to `Pivot`. But we do not have `styles` attribute for `PivotItem`.

```
const pivotStyles:IPivotStyles = {
  link: {},
  linkContent: {},
  linkIsSelected: {},
  text: {},
  icon: {},
  count: {},
  root: {
    //background: DefaultPalette.greenDark
  }
};
```

How can I apply style to `PivotItem` so that I can add width to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PivotItem` styles could be adjusted via `Pivot.styles` property, at least the following styles could be set:

- `link`
- `linkContent`
- `linkIsSelected`

[image]

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to set fixed `width` for pivot link:

```
const pivotStyles: Partial<IStyleSet<IPivotStyles>> = {
  link: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  linkIsSelected: {
    width: "300px"
  }
};
```

where

```
const tabsItems = [
  {
    content: "Pivot #1",
    header: "My Files"
  },
  {
    content: "Pivot #2",
    header: "Recent"
  },
  {
    content: "Pivot #3",
    header: "Shared with me"
  }
];

export const PivotBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Pivot styles={pivotStyles}>
      {tabsItems.map((tabItem,idx) => (
        <PivotItem key={idx} headerText={tabItem.header}>
          <Label>{tabItem.content}</Label>
        </PivotItem>
      ))}
    </Pivot>
  );
};
```